# Ratio test or not to

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that my sum converges absolutely.

Wolfram is telling me that it knows the series
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^mm!}{(2m)!}$$
converges by the ratio test. According to my book the ratio test can only be done for series that are $a_n\geq0$ for all $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

since my series is alternating that can not be used. Is it that taking the absolut value of the sequence in the series converges by the ratio test and that implies that the original series is convergent?

Comment: Don't you know a theorem for alternating series :-)?

Comment: @Axel I know a few

Comment: @Axel if the positive series converges would the original series then converge?

Comment: That's right, if the series converges absolutely then it converges.

Comment: Another way of saying the same thing: let $b_1, b_2, \cdots,$ be a sequence of strictly positive elements, such that $B = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ is a convergent series, and let $a_n = (-1)^n b_n.$  Since $B$ is finite, $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = 0.$  Therefore, per the [Alternating Series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), you have that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is a convergent series.

Comment: @user2661923 You're ignoring an important hypothesis in the alternating series test.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Nice catch.  You mean that $b_n$ must be strictly decreasing.  My oversight.  Fortunately, the analagous $b_n$ are strictly decreasing in the original poster's question.

Comment: @user2661923 **Strictly** decreasing is not necessary. You just need $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ decreasing eventually, and $a_n \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call $a_m = \dfrac{(-1)^m m!}{(2m)!}$.

Use the ratio test with $(|a_m|)_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$, it gives you that $\sum |a_m|$ converges therefore $\sum a_m$ is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the ratio test to the series$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left|\frac{(-1)^mm!}{(2m)!}\right|=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{m!}{(2m)!}$$and deduce that it converges. So, your series is absolutely convergent, and therefore it converges.